# Django filter a reverse relationship of each item in a queryset

Tags: python, django, filter, django-queryset

So i have 3 models

```
class User(models.Model):

class UserQuestions(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User)
      question = models.ForeignKey(Question)

class UserAnswers(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User)
      question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

I want to get a list of all the users, but i want to filter their userquestion_set and useranswer_set by a field of the question and then annotate the queryset with a count for the sum of userquestions_set and useranswer_set.

if i do something like:

```
User.objects.filter(Q(userquestions__question_field=value)&Q(useranswers__question_field=value)).annotate
```

It filters my Users, i want to filter their set of userquestions and useranswers so that they contain only the questions which have that field equal with my value, in order to get a proper annotation for the rows in the queryset.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with `UserQuestions.objects.filter(question__field=value)`?

Comment: I modified my question and added more information. Basically i need the Users with the annotation and that is why i can't do from the other 2 models. Getting each user and filtering twice for each user and making a list is also out of the question because it takes too much and makes too many queries to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.

The resulting rows that your query will be evaluated across are similar to:

```
id | userquestion__id | userquestion__user_id | userquestion__value | usweranswer__id | useranswer__user_id | useranswer__value
```

for all combinations of `User`, `UserQuest`  and `UserAnswer` where `*__user_id` equals `id`. So when you `&` your `Q` objects together, you only consider rows that match both `Q` objects.  This is why your annotations will only work for users having both questions and answers that match your criteria. All other `User`s are filtered away.

Using `|` for the `Q` objects won't help you much either, because the unmatched criteria will count as false positives and vice versa.

So your only option is to first load all the users, then load all the users with the right answer annotated with answer count, and then load all the users with the right question annotated with question count. Finally you should annotate users with the relevant counts.

**Edit (Example):**
The following is not tested, and I apology for my rusty Python:

```
users = User.objects.all()
users_with_right_answers = defaultdict(
    int,
    {
        user.id: user.right_answer_count for user in User.objects.filter(
            useranswer__value='...').annotate(
            right_answer_count=Count('useranswer')
    }
)
users_with_right_questions = defaultdict(
    int,
    {
        user.id: user.right_question_count for user in User.objects.filter(
            userquestion__value='...').annotate(
            right_question_count=Count('userquestion')
    }
)

for user in users:
    user.right_answer_count = users_with_right_answers[user.id]
    user.right_question_count = users_with_right_questions[user.id]
```

The idea is that we get to do everything in three simple queries, since it is not possible to do in just one.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand, how would i achieve that? how do i do it? Can you give an example please?>

Comment: this method is very expensive, if i have alot of data it would take forever

Comment: I fail to see how this method is expensive.  It does three queries in total.  If that takes forever, doing it in one query would also take forever.

Comment: there are three fors to run, on thousands of rows of data, the queries aren't the expensive part here, the for methods would take long

Comment: Django is going to iterate through the fetched rows and create User instances for each of them in order to evaluate a query.  So you have the for loop anyway.  My approach is still only a constant factor slower than what you could ever have hoped for.  I am convinced that this constant is pretty close to three.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I want to help you out here; O(n) + O(2n) is still just O(n).  In the absense of a better solution, please try out mine.  If you experience performance issues because of thousands of users each with hundres of answers and questions, the performance issue might be fixed by proper indexing. I will be happy to assist in that regards too.